# ng-repeat in a table with colspan and rowspan

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feniixx/23basm8m/1/) with the desired table and the Javascript function containing the array from where I want to populate the table, what I don't figure out is how, because if I use `rowspan` and `colspan` I have to create different `<tr>` for each product...

If there's another way to get the desired table I'd love to know about it... The main question here is: How could I use `ng-repeat` in a table that uses rowspan and colspan?

Also, the colspan and rowspan values at the `<thead>` can't be static as in the jsfiddle since each row may contain different amount of products... So the second question is: How could I dynamically set the `rowspan` value? they should be specified in each table row..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible if you let the `rowspan` depend on `inventory.length` for the current transaction, and then you use nested `ng-repeat`s.

Here we go:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.hello = 123;
    vm.transactions = [{
        id: 1,
        cost: 100,
        transaction_type: { id: 1, name: 'Sell' },
        client: { id: 2, name: 'XCLIENT' },
        inventory: [
            { id: 1, quantity: 4, product: { id: 1, name: 'Cup' }, product_condition: { id: 2, name: 'New' } },
            { id: 2, quantity: 10, product: { id: 2, name: 'Shirt' }, product_condition: { id: 2, name: 'New' } }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        cost: 40,
        transaction_type: { id: 2, name: 'Buy' },
        supplier: { id: 3, name: 'XSUPPLIER' },
        inventory: [
            { id: 1, quantity: 2, product: { id: 1, name: 'Cup' }, product_condition: { id: 2, name: 'New' } },
            { id: 2, quantity: 5, product: { id: 6, name: 'Pants' }, product_condition: { id: 2, name: 'New' } }
        ]
    }];
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <thead>
      <div>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan=2>Movement</td>
          <td colspan=3>Products</td>
          <td rowspan=2>Supplier</td>
          <td rowspan=2>Cost</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Condition</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="t in transactions">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{t.inventory.length}}">Sell</td>
        <td>{{t.inventory[0].product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{t.inventory[0].quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{t.inventory[0].product_condition.name}}</td>
        <td rowspan="{{t.inventory.length}}">XCLIENT</td>
        <td rowspan="{{t.inventory.length}}">$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in t.inventory" ng-if="$index > 0">
        <td>{{item.product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{item.product_condition.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/23basm8m/4/)

Comment: There's a thing with your answer, the first product listed is static, the one that is Cup, 4, New...

Comment: Thanks!!, If you know about a way to have it all in a single `<tr>` it would be awesome! I mean the whole `transaction` data including the products...

Comment: That's not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: I believe instead of `ng-if` you can do `ng-repeat="item in t.inventory.slice(1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here it is the totally dynamic way including dynamic rowspan :

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <h3>Here's what I want it to be</h3>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">  

  <table >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>Movement</td>
        <td colspan='{{rowspan}}'>Products</td>
        <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>Supplier</td>
        <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>Cost</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Condition</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat='t in transactions'>     
      <tr ng-init='invCustom=(t.invetory.splice(1))'>
        <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{t.transaction_type.name}}</td>

        <td>{{t.invetory[0].product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{t.invetory[0].quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{t.invetory[0].product_condition.name}}</td>

        <td ng-if='$index==0' rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{t.client.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if='$index==1' rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{t.supplier.name}}</td>
        <td rowspan='{{rowspan}}'>{{ t.cost | currency }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat='tsub in invCustom'> 
        <td>{{tsub.product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{tsub.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{tsub.product_condition.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>  
  </table>
  </div>
    <h4>This data isn't loaded from the controller, I'd like to know how to use ng-repead in this case</h4>

</div>
```

JS:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
 //var vm = this;
  $scope.rowspan = 3;
  $scope.transactions = [{
    id: 1,
    cost: 100,
    transaction_type: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Sell'
    },
    client: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'XCLIENT'
    },
    invetory: [{
      id: 1,
      quantity: 4,
      product: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Cup'
      },
      product_condition: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'New'
      }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 10,
      product: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Shirt'
      },
      product_condition: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'New'
      }
    },
     {
      id: 3,
      quantity: 101,
      product: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Shirt_C'
      },
      product_condition: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'New_C'
      }
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    cost: 40,
    transaction_type: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Buy'
    },
    supplier: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'XSUPPLIER'
    },
    invetory: [{
      id: 1,
      quantity: 2,
      product: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Cup'
      },
      product_condition: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'New'
      }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 5,
      product: {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Pants'
      },
      product_condition: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'New'
      }
    },
              {
      id: 3,
      quantity: 55,
      product: {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Pants_C'
      },
      product_condition: {
        id: 8,
        name: 'New_C'
      }
    }]
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code and do not forgot to include angular  JS library....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js
"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h3>Here's what I want it to be</h3>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
  <table >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Movement</td>
        <td colspan=3>Products</td>
        <td rowspan=2>Supplier</td>
        <td rowspan=2>Cost</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Condition</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat='t in transactions' ng-init='i=0'>     
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>{{t.transaction_type.name}}</td>

        <td>{{t.invetory[i].product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{t.invetory[i].quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{t.invetory[i].product_condition.name}}</td>

        <td ng-if='$index==0' rowspan=2>{{t.client.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if='$index==1' rowspan=2>{{t.supplier.name}}</td>
        <td rowspan=2>{{ t.cost | currency }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>        
         <td>{{t.invetory[i+1].product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{t.invetory[i+1].quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{t.invetory[i+1].product_condition.name}}</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  </div>
    <h4>This data isn't loaded from the controller, I'd like to know how to use ng-repead in this case</h4>

</div>
```

Comment: This limits the rowspan to just two products, what I need is a dynamic rowspan per table row, do you mind making a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

> How could I use ng-repeat in a table that uses rowspan and colspan?

Yes you can use, I will put a very basic example and not fix the entire thing for you.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in mylist">
        <td ng-if="someCondition2" rowspan="2">AAA</td>
        <td ng-if="someCondition1" colspan="2">BBB</td>
        <td ng-if="someCondition3">CCC</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

This way you can conditionally add rowspan or colspan where ever required, hope you get the idea.

Comment: There wouldn't be a problem for me if there would be a single `<tr>`, if you could help making the table look like the jsfiddle and having the `ng-repeat` just in one `<tr>` then your answer would be helpful

Comment: What I thought was to put the ng-repeat in the `<tbody>` tag, but that's bad practice, but basically my problem is also related to the `colspan` and `rowspan` values at the `<thead>` they can't be static, they must be calculated for each table row...